# Invalid Certificate when adding Gmail account to Apple Mail

Tags: certificates, email

Trouble seemed to start after upgrading to OS X 10.9.  I stopped receiving email in an account I'd set up over a year ago.  I removed the account and when I attempted to add it again, I was served a message about the identity of my domain name not being verifiable.  Not suggesting it has anything to do with the OS X upgrade, just providing related details.

As of right now, I'm unable to find any info about agoragr.gr and it has me confused/concerned.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated.

Mark

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Renew the certificate on the domain, if you can't contact the administrators.

Comment: I've never had a certificate. Domain was registered through GoDaddy a few years ago and DNS is now handled through HostGator.  I'll contact GD, see where that leads.

Comment: Should it concern me that agoragr.gr is hosted on the same server as my domain?  Is Google just searching desperately for an SSL certificate?

Comment: If it's shared hosting then I expect this to be common practice. If you need SSL they will require an IP just for you (this is the way ssl works)

Comment: Thanks @Lucas. I was just a little thrown when I realized they were on the same server.  Been dealing with Google Apps and shared hosting for years and it's the first time I've noticed this.